# Конвеер из 3-х процессов соединенных c помощью pipe

Tags: c++, linux

Добрый день. Не выходит реализовать конвеер из 3-х процессов соединенных с помощью pipe. В стандартный поток ввода 3-го процесса ничего не поступает.  Конвеер из 2-х процессов работает.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//Инициализация имени архива и прототипа
  if (argc != 3){
     cerr << "Parameters count is not correct!" << endl;
     exit(1);
  }
  //порождаем дочерний процесс для выполнения ar.
  int fds[2];
  pipe(fds);
  if (fork()){ 
     //Перенаправляем вывод в программный канал
     dup2(fds[1],1);
     execl("/bin/ar", "ar", "-t", argv[1], NULL);
  }
  else { //дочерний процесс
      int fds2[2];
      pipe(fds2);
      if (fork()){
         dup2(fds[0],0);
         dup2(fds2[1],1);
         execl("/bin/grep", "grep", argv[2], NULL);
       }else {
          dup2(fds2[0],0);
          char buf[100];
          read(0,buf,100);
          cerr << buf << endl;
        }
   }
   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

1. В зависимости от дистрибутива (например у меня) `ar` может находиться в `/usr/bin/`, а не в `/bin/`.
2. Вывод у вас сделан неправильно, так как массив `buf` заполнен мусором из стека и он будет выводится в дополнение к прочитанным байтам, да и для того, чтобы прочитать все данные может потребоваться несколько `read()`.
3. Посмотрите после запуска `ps`, появились порождённые фоновые процессы ожидающие ввода. Они ждут данных из трубы, так как другой конец её (write end) ещё открыт в каком-то процессе (а именно в том же самом). Чтобы этого не происходило, в процессах, где дескриптор одного из конца трубы не нужен, его надо закрывать.

С учётом всего этого:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
//Инициализация имени архива и прототипа
  if (argc != 3){
     cerr << "Parameters count is not correct!" << endl;
     exit(1);
  }
  //порождаем дочерний процесс для выполнения ar.
  int fds[2];
  pipe(fds);
  if (fork()){
     close(fds[0]); //- здесь читать из трубы не будем
     //Перенаправляем вывод в программный канал
     dup2(fds[1],1);
     execl("/bin/ar", "ar", "-t", argv[1], NULL);
  }
  else { //дочерний процесс
      close(fds[1]); //- а дальше сюда не нужно писать
      int fds2[2];
      pipe(fds2);
      if (fork()){
         close(fds2[0]);
         dup2(fds[0],0);
         dup2(fds2[1],1);
         execl("/bin/grep", "grep", argv[2], NULL);
       } else {
          close(fds[0]);
          close(fds2[1]);
          dup2(fds2[0],0);
          char buf[100];
          int i;
          while((i=read(0, buf, sizeof buf))>0) write(2, buf, i);
        }
   }
   return 0;
 }
```