# Получить Ввод/вывод процесса

Tags: linux, c

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно создать процесс и получить его ввод/вывод. В libc есть popen и можно получить либо ввод, либо вывод. Мне нужно получить и то и то.

Делитесь пожалуйста идеями :)

Comment: Получить ввод - это как?

Comment: не правильно выразился. Получить файл ввода, ну как бы FILE*.

Comment: popen имеет ограниченные возможности, надо использовать низкоуровневые вызовы, смотрите пример перенаправления: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474094/130
Чтобы получить из `FILE*` stdio низкоуровневый дескриптор используйте `fileno`, наоборот - `fdopen`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы получить как ввод так и вывод дочернего процесса, можно их перенаправить, используя [dup2()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) (исполняемый псевдо-код):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import *

STDIN_FILENO, STDOUT_FILENO = 0, 1
r_stdin, w_stdin = pipe()
r_stdout, w_stdout = pipe()
if not fork():  # child process
    close(w_stdin)  # unused
    close(r_stdout)  # unused

    dup2(r_stdin, STDIN_FILENO)  # redirect stdin
    close(r_stdin)
    dup2(w_stdout, STDOUT_FILENO)  # redirect stdout
    close(w_stdout)
    execlp('cat', 'cat')
else:  # parent
    close(r_stdin)  # unused
    close(w_stdout)  # unused

    write(w_stdin, b'hello')  # send some input to the child
    close(w_stdin)
    output = read(r_stdout, 512)  # read it back
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, b'got [' + output + b']\n')
    close(r_stdout)
    wait()  # wait for the child to exit
```

По сути это реализация [шагов из @Pink Tux ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530417/23044).

Стоит упомянуть, что на практике многие программы изменяют своё поведение, если их стандартные ввод/вывод перенаправлены в pipe. В частности из-за внутренней буферизации ввод/вывод может быть задержан, например, без `--line-buffered` опции `grep` не сразу найденные строчки может печатать, если его вывод перенаправлен. Возможно следует использовать псевдо-tty (pty) вместо pipe. See [Q: Why not just use a pipe (popen())?](http://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/FAQ.html#whynotpipe)

---

Для сравнения вот полный C код, соответствующий вышеприведённому псевдо-коду:

```c
/** Redirect both stdin/stdout of a child process. Test it.
 *
 *   $ gcc *.c && ./a.out
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define Close(FD) do {                                  \
    int Close_fd = (FD);                                \
    if (close(Close_fd) == -1) {                        \
      perror("close");                                  \
      fprintf(stderr, "%s:%d: close(" #FD ") %d\n",     \
              __FILE__, __LINE__, Close_fd);            \
    }                                                   \
  }while(0)


static int child = 0; /* whether it is a child process relative to main() */

static void report_error_and_exit(const char* msg) {
  perror(msg);
  (child ? _exit : exit)(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/** move oldfd to newfd */
static void redirect(int oldfd, int newfd) {
  if (oldfd != newfd) {
    if (dup2(oldfd, newfd) != -1)
      Close(oldfd); /* successfully redirected */
    else
      report_error_and_exit("dup2");
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int fd_stdin[2], fd_stdout[2]; /* stdin/stdout pipes */
  if (pipe(fd_stdin) == -1)
    report_error_and_exit("stdin pipe");
  if (pipe(fd_stdout) == -1)
    report_error_and_exit("stdout pipe");

  switch(fork()) {
  case -1: /* error */
    report_error_and_exit("fork");
  case 0: /* child: redirect stdin/stdout and exec */
    child = 1;
    Close(fd_stdin[1]);  /* close unused end of the pipe */
    Close(fd_stdout[0]); /* unused */

    redirect(fd_stdin[0], STDIN_FILENO);   /* redirect stdin */
    redirect(fd_stdout[1], STDOUT_FILENO); /* redirect stdout */

    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);
    report_error_and_exit("execlp");
  default: /* parent: write some input to the child and read it back */
    Close(fd_stdin[0]);  /* close unused end of the pipe */
    Close(fd_stdout[1]); /* unused */

    { /* send some input to the child */
      char buf[] = "hello";
      if (write(fd_stdin[1], buf, sizeof buf) == -1)
        report_error_and_exit("write");
      Close(fd_stdin[1]);
    }    
    { /* read it back */
      char readbuf[512] = {0};
      ssize_t n = read(fd_stdout[0], readbuf, sizeof readbuf);
      if (n == -1)
        report_error_and_exit("read");
      Close(fd_stdout[0]);
      printf("got [%.*s]\n", (int)n, readbuf);
    }
    { /* wait for the child to exit */
      int status = 0;
      if (wait(&status) == -1)
        report_error_and_exit("wait");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Как-то так:

1. Создали 2 канала ([man pipe](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=2&russian=2&topic=pipe)) - на чтение и на запись
2. [Форкнулись](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fork&russian=2)
3. В потомке эти дескрипторы замкнули на stdin и stdout
4. Заместили потомка нужным процессом при помощи чего-нибудь из семейства [exec*](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=exec&category=3)

Comment: [dup2()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/dup.2.html) стоит упомянуть.